# Prove or disprove that accumulation of a set is $(0,0)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Let $ S = \left\{ \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m}, 0\right)\; : \; n, m\in \mathbb{N} \right\} $ 
How can i prove formally that there's a single Accumulation point on S, intuitively i think is $(0,0)$.

Is $S$ defined by a sequence?

Comment: There are infinitely many accumulation points besides $(0,0)$, namely $(1,0)$, $(1/2,0)$, and so on. The interior of the set is empty: perhaps you're confusing terminology.

Comment: For each $n$ the point $(1/n, 0)$ is the limit of the sequence $a_m = (1/n + 1/m, 0)$ so there are many accumulation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have already mentioned, there are an infinite number of accumulation  points.

Since the title of your question was a little misleading, let's settle some definitions real quick:

- An **accumulation point**, or **limit point**, $x$ of some subset $S$ of a topological space is a point where every neighborhood of $x$ also contains some point in $S$ other than $x$.
- When we're talking about sequences of points $x_i$ in, say, a metric space, we could also characterize limit points as being the limit of some *subsequence* of $x_i$. This points towards James's comment above:

First note that the sequence defined by $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ converges to 0 as $n$ approaches infinity.

If you take the set $S = \{(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m},0)\}$ and fix one of the variables (say, $m$), it becomes apparent that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m} = \frac{1}{m}$. Thus we can construct a sequence in $S$ that converges to $\frac{1}{m}$ for each $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Far from just one accumulation point!

You can also use this kind of thinking to show that $(0,0)$ is a limit point: take $m=n$, and construct a sequence in $S$ where $x_n$ = $\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n}$. The rest should be easy (though, see if you can relate it to some fact about the limit points *of the set of limit points*!).